# Contando frequências em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o código abaixo que funciona para contar frequências em uma lista. Porém, o  output deste código é um `NoneType` e, por isso, não consigo usar métodos como `.sort()`, por exemplo, para organizar a saída de forma a mostrar em ordem descendente.

Gostaria que o resultado saísse na forma de uma tabela ou dicionário, mas não `NoneType`.

```
def frequency(my_list): 

    # Creating an empty dictionary  
    freq = {} 
    for item in my_list: 
        if (item in freq): 
            freq[item] += 1
        else: 
            freq[item] = 1

    for key, value in freq.items(): 
        print (" % d : % d"%(key, value)) 

my_list =[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2] 

final_list = frequency(my_list)
```

Comment: é só sua função retornar o que ela calculou, com o comando `return`  - `return freq` na última linha, no caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz uma expressão do tipo:

```
variavel = funcao()
```

O valor que será atribuiído à variável será o valor **retornado** pela função. Por omissão o Python retornará `None`. Isto é, se você não fizer explicitamente um `return` na sua função indicando o que deseja que ela retorne o valor retornado será nulo.

A sua função não possui retorno, por isso o valor atribuído é nulo. Para corrigir isso, basta especificar qual deve ser o valor retornado:

```
def frequency(my_list): 
    freq = {} 
    for item in my_list: 
        if (item in freq): 
            freq[item] += 1
        else: 
            freq[item] = 1
    return freq
```

Assim, o valor de `final_list` será o dicionário que você criou em `freq`.

Algumas dicas que poderão ser úteis em algum momento nos seus estudos:

**1.** A classe `dict` possui um método chamado [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) que pode ser utilizado para retornar um valor em uma chave omissa. Assim, ao invés de fazer:

```
if item in freq:
  freq[item] += 1
else:
  freq[item] = 1
```

Você pode fazer apenas:

```
freq[item] = freq.get(item, 0) + 1
```

**2.** No Python existe a classe [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) que já implementa toda essa lógica de atribuir um valor padrão em chaves omissas no dicionário. No construtor você passa um objeto chamável que será invocado sempre que for necessário definir o valor omisso no dicionário. A própria classe `int`, sem parâmetros, retornará o valor 0, então poderia fazer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

freq = defaultdict(int)

...
freq[item] += 1
```

Assim podendo fazer `freq[item] += 1` sem verificar se existe a chave ou não, pois se não existir será criada com o valor 0 e já incrementada em 1.

**3.** Você pode utilizar a classe [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) para calcular a frequência dos valores em uma sequência.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Se não for problema, você poderia usar o módulo numpy. Segue o código:

```
import numpy as np

def frequency(my_list): 
    freq = {}
    # Função "unique" retorna um array com todos elementos existentes
    # uma única vez (sem repetição).
    for item in np.unique(np.array(my_list)):
        # Pesquisa na lista a frequencia de cada elemento
        # A função "where" retorna um array com os índices onde ocorre o item.
        # A ideia é só usar o tamanho desse array que sabemos a frequência.
         freq[item] = np.where(np.array(my_list)==item)[0].shape[0]

    for key, value in freq.items(): 
        print (" % d : % d"%(key, value)) 

my_list =[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2] 

final_list = frequency(my_list)
```

Saída:

```
  1 :  5
  2 :  4
  3 :  3
  4 :  3
  5 :  2
```